My App Installed From Debian Package Can't Access File Beneath /usr/share
I recently created a Debian package for my Gtk 3.0 app and tested installing it onto a live Ubuntu Budgie 24.04 session. The install itself worked just fine. The app is run from the system menu and everything seems normal except that it cannot access the one file it needs that was installed in the app's folder beneath /usr/share -- its help documentation file that should open when the user clicks "Help" on the app's menu. Instead, the app displays a "permission denied" error. Okay, so my user is the "live user" logged into the live session and perhaps this user doesn't have the necessary permissions to "read" a file stored beneath /usr/share? What puzzles me is that although I can't access this file via my newly installed app, I can open a terminal and cat the file's contents just fine. What is it about my app that makes it behave different from the terminal app when reading this file? The file's permissions are set as "644" and all enclosing directories as "755" with the owner of everything being "root". ???

Of course, /usr/share is read-only. With help from an outside source, I found that my app wasn't just attempting to read beneath /usr/share. It was also trying to write there as well and hence the "permission denied" error. I merely assumed (yeah, I know) that this was permission denied to read.
